# Proof of this trivial Ramanujan result

Tags: number-theory, summation, ramanujan-summation

The title is obviously sarcastic, and, sorry for my ignorance.
Where can I find proofs for Ramanujan results like

$$1-1+1-1+1+...= \frac{1}{2}$$

$$1+2+3+4+5+...=-\frac{1}{12}$$

I don't seem to find anything around here... Thanks for the help!

Comment: I feel like I've seen these with respect to the Riemann zeta function. But I've never even taken Complex Analysis, so I wouldn't know details beyond that.

Answer (score 3):

Your first question has been asked before here:

[Checking my understanding: $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - ... = \frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635324/checking-my-understanding-1-1-1-1-1-frac12)

[$1−1+1−1+1−1+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}$ proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303314/1-11-11-1-cdots-frac-12-proof)

Your second question has an answer here:

[Why does $1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112)

There are also several similar questions on this site for example:

[$1-2+3-4+\dots = \frac{1}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460388/1-23-4-dots-frac14)

[Series of logarithms $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln(k)$ (Ramanujan summation?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39378/series-of-logarithms-sum-limits-k-1-infty-lnk-ramanujan-summation)

[Is it possible to assign a value to the sum of primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84642/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-value-to-the-sum-of-primes)

[Is my $1+1+1+1+1...=-\frac{1}{2}$ proof correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210979/is-my-11111-frac12-proof-correct)

More aboute the methods used to extract a finite number from divergent series can be found for example in:

[Analytic continuation -Easy explanation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41938/analytic-continuation-easy-explanation/41941#41941)

[Zeta function zeros and analytic continuation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378803/zeta-function-zeros-and-analytic-continuation/379810#379810)

Answer (score -2):

For $1-1+1-1+1-\ldots =\frac{1}{2}$

Consider the sum $(1-1)+(1-1)+\ldots= 0+0+\ldots =0$

Now shift the parenthesis one number down so we have $1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\ldots=1+0+0+\ldots=1$

Taking the average of the two yields $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I was more interested in a proof involving the Riemann zeta function. Your answer is intuitive, but I was looking for formalism! :)

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide on how to write mathematical formulas on this site using mathjax/latex.